# How to import actionscript 3 flash game into flash builder?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm newbie in this area, and I would like to have an android app that can play my AcionScript game. My actonscript game consist of external sound and image.

How do I import my ActionScript file into flash builder?

Should I import my codes or my SWF file alone is enough?
Where should I import my external files?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous options, such as:

#### Flash Pro

If your game has already been created in Flash Pro, you could simply target AIR for Android from Flash Pro's publish settings:

> [image: flash-pro]

#### ADT Command Line Packager

Likewise, you could simply use the [ADT command line packager](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html) to build your SWF to an Android distributable.

#### Flash Builder

Otherwise from Flash Builder, you can create a new ActionScript mobile project:

> [image: new-project]

Select Android, or other target platforms:

> [image: project-settings]

Place code and packages relative to the src/ folder, same as you would relative to your FLA:

> [image: packages]

Your entire Flash app could be published as a SWC, then instantiated from Flash Builder, or individual assets may be exported as SWCs:

> [image: swc-publish]

Likewise you can programmatically embed SWF assets in ActionScript classes using the embed metadata tag:

```
[Embed(source="asset.swf", symbol="symbol")]
private var SymbolClass:Class;

var symbol:MovieClip = new SymbolClass();
```